# Full screen button disappeared from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fullscreen

Recently, the button to switch a universal app to full has disappeared. This is the case across all universal/store apps, and for the life of me I can't figure out why it's gone, and how to get it back.

The standard close, minimize, and maximize buttons are still there:

[image: Window without full screen button]

But this button is no longer there

[image: Window with full screen button]

Any ideas how to get this back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This button is only available for **non universal/older** Windows 8 Apps. Those apps have to button to switch to fullscreen. Looks like your app got an update to make it to a Windows 10 universal app (UWP).